# What is a good site for book recommendations?

Tags: discussion

It seems this site does not allow book recommendations. Where is a good place to get recommendations from people who are very familiar with the sci-fi genre?

Comment: Closing this as duplicate since the other is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) is always open for book recommendations. And we have a fortnightly [Recommendation Chat Event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley?tab=schedule) that is specific to book/movie/comicbook/whateveryouwant recommendations. The next event is scheduled for this Wednesday (Dec 28th) and happens again every two weeks after that.

Answer (score 0):

As OghmaOsiris mentioned, the chat room is a great place for sci-fi recommendations.

Another possibility is the [Literature Stackexchange beta site](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).  While they are not focused on sci-fi, they do allow book recommendation requests on a [trial basis, with specific criteria](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/policy-trial-notice-book-recommendations).